# Load session_start() only if session does not exist?

Tags: php, session

is there a short code trick to check if a session has started and if not then load one? Currently I receive an error "session already started..." if I put in a session start regardless of checking.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`isset` is generally the proper way to check if predefined variables are currently defined:

**If you are using a version of php prior to 5.4**,

you can usually get away with and its tempting just doing the code below, but be aware that if for some reason sessions are disabled, session_start() will still be called which could end up leading to errors and needless debugging since the $_SESSION array isn't allowed to be created.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
```

if you want to account for checking to see if sessions are disabled for some reason, you can supress the error message, set a test session variable, and then verify it was set.  If its not, you can code in a reaction for disabled sessions.  You'll want to do all this at or near the start of your script.  So as an example(works differently depending on error handling setting):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
$_SESSION['valid'] = 'valid';
if($_SESSION['valid'] != 'valid')
{
   //handle disabled sessions
}
```

**However, if you are using php version 5.4 or greater**,

You can use the [session_status()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php) function, a better option as it accounts for sessions being disabled and checks if a session already exists.

```
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE){session_start();}
```

NOTE that **PHP_SESSION_NONE** is a constant set by PHP and therefore does not need to be wrapped in quotes.  It evaluates to integer 1, but as its a constant that was specifically set to eliminate the need for magic numbers, best to test against the constant.

Comment: @nick well, I'd say you'very either found a bug in 5.4.16 or more likely have a weird php/server config.  Either way it's good to kbow their maybe edge cases :D

Comment: This isn't working in a PHPUnit context. Error returned is `session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:110)`.

Answer (score 8):

Many people simply use `@session_start()` to suppress the warning that the session has already been started. The alternative is usually:

```
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();
```

Comment: This isn't working in a PHPUnit context. Error returned is `session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:110)`.

Answer (score 3):

try this condition

```
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '<')) {
 if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
 } }else{
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
} }
```

If you only want to avoid the error, use @ before the function
example:

```
@session_start();
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Could you please edit your post to explain what your code does and how it solves the OP's problem? Code only answers are discouraged and are subject to deletion.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (session_id() === "") { session_start(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for existing session before starting new:

```
   // # if phpversion() is >= 5.4
  if(phpversion() >= 5.4) {

    // # check session_status() function for value 'PHP_SESSION_NONE'
    if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
      session_start();
    }

  } else { // # maintain backwards compat. with PHP versions older than 5.4

      // # if $_SESSION object if NOT set, start a new session!
      if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
      }
  }
```