# How to syntax the session_start(); if in a separate php file

Tags: php, session, syntax, session-variables

I have a contact form that links to an external php file (because I have a single-scrolling page with all content on it, ran by jQuery and it wouldn't make sense to have it all as a .php file as would be the case with a single, separate contact page).

My question is, since I have a captcha to protect against spam and such, I have to include the `session_start();` in both the contact php file and the captcha. My question is would I syntax it in the contact.php file as:

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
```

and then have more php here, i.e. - my contact form script
        ?>

or just have it be the first line as:
        session_start();
after the initial php tags?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: cant get your question clearly

Comment: <?php session_start(); ?> as the first line will allow  session values to be shared between the other php page

Comment: this is what I want to know: 
Since I will have more code (obviously) in the contact.php page - it wouldn't be proper to start the session_start(); in it's own <?php> tags will it?

I ask because the place where I learned it is having the php above the head of the contact page where the form will be instead of a separate php file like I have. In their demo, they have 
        <?php session_start(); ?>
and then the HTML metadata and head tags, with the php in the body (enclosed with new <?php> tags)

So, in my separate php file I should just have the  session_start(); in the same <?php> tags?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `session_start();` at top of all your php codes to apply a session.

```
<?php

session_start();
$user='New User';
$_SESSION['user']=$user;

//Print this line on another php code you will get the same username
echo "Welcome $_SESSION['user']";
?>
```

Comment: yes I know this. I think I have my question answered though. If I get errors or bad results, I'll just play around with it. There can only be a few possibilities so I'm sure I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear. You should probably try this code at the top of the page.

```
<?php
    @session_start();
?>
```

check this link
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

or this [Load session_start() only if session does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093264/load-session-start-only-if-session-does-not-exist)

Comment: Would this code not run `session_start()` twice, once to check if it can, and once again if it did for the check?

Comment: I think it does. Sorry about that.

Comment: Never use error muting (@). You should check if session is started instead of this (`if (!isset(S_SESSION)) { session_start(); }`)

Comment: Yeah it suppress the warning. That second link has explained perfectly.